# How can I get this type carosol slider in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello Here I need a carosol slider like this one,
In full screen view height 250-300, width Get.width.

[image]

Can anyone help me please to get this carosol slider in flutter.

Comment: "I need" is not a question. What have you tried so far, what exactly do you need help with, how is your current code look like?

Answer (score 1):

I made this widget, I haven't tested it with Images, but in principle it works:

```dart
class Carrousel extends StatelessWidget {
  Carrousel({
    Key? key,
    required this.children,
    required this.height,
    required this.delay,
    this.selectedColor,
    this.color,
    this.fit = BoxFit.contain,
  })  : assert(children.isNotEmpty),
        super(key: key);

  final List<Widget> children;
  final double height;
  final Color? selectedColor;
  final Color? color;
  final Duration delay;
  final BoxFit fit;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool justChanged = false;
    final width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final currentChild = ValueNotifier<Widget>(children.first);
    Timer.periodic(
      delay,
      (_) {
        int newIndex = children.indexOf(currentChild.value) + 1;
        if (newIndex == children.length) {
          newIndex = 0;
        }
        if (!justChanged) {
          currentChild.value = children[newIndex];
        } else {
          justChanged = false;
        }
      },
    );
    return SizedBox(
      width: width,
      height: height,
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          ValueListenableBuilder<Widget>(
            valueListenable: currentChild,
            builder: (context, child, _) {
              return SizedBox(
                width: width,
                height: height,
                child: child,
              );
            },
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: width,
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: ValueListenableBuilder<Widget>(
                valueListenable: currentChild,
                builder: (context, _currentChild, __) {
                  return Row(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: children.map<Widget>((child) {
                      Color _color = color ?? Colors.grey;
                      if (child == _currentChild) {
                        _color = selectedColor ?? Colors.white;
                      }
                      return Card(
                        shape: const CircleBorder(),
                        elevation: 7,
                        child: SizedBox(
                          height: height * 0.05,
                          child: CircleAvatar(
                            backgroundColor: _color,
                            child: InkWell(
                              customBorder: const CircleBorder(),
                              onTap: () {
                                justChanged = true;
                                currentChild.value = child;
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here for you to try:

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Carrousel',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final random = Random(DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch);
    final lenght = random.nextInt(5) + 2;
    final List<Color> colors = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < lenght; i++) {
      colors.add(Color.fromRGBO(
        random.nextInt(0xff),
        random.nextInt(0xff),
        random.nextInt(0xff),
        1,
      ));
    }
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Carrousel'),
      ),
      body: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
        child: Carrousel(
          height: 300,
          delay: const Duration(seconds: 5),
          children: colorsWidgets(colors),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  List<Widget> colorsWidgets(List<Color> colors) {
    return colors.map<Widget>(
      (color) {
        return Container(color: color);
      },
    ).toList();
  }
}

class Carrousel extends StatelessWidget {
  Carrousel({
    Key? key,
    required this.children,
    required this.height,
    required this.delay,
    this.selectedColor,
    this.color,
    this.fit = BoxFit.contain,
  })  : assert(children.isNotEmpty),
        super(key: key);

  final List<Widget> children;
  final double height;
  final Color? selectedColor;
  final Color? color;
  final Duration delay;
  final BoxFit fit;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool justChanged = false;
    final width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final currentChild = ValueNotifier<Widget>(children.first);
    Timer.periodic(
      delay,
      (_) {
        int newIndex = children.indexOf(currentChild.value) + 1;
        if (newIndex == children.length) {
          newIndex = 0;
        }
        if (!justChanged) {
          currentChild.value = children[newIndex];
        } else {
          justChanged = false;
        }
      },
    );
    return SizedBox(
      width: width,
      height: height,
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          ValueListenableBuilder<Widget>(
            valueListenable: currentChild,
            builder: (context, child, _) {
              return SizedBox(
                width: width,
                height: height,
                child: child,
              );
            },
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: width,
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: ValueListenableBuilder<Widget>(
                valueListenable: currentChild,
                builder: (context, _currentChild, __) {
                  return Row(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: children.map<Widget>((child) {
                      Color _color = color ?? Colors.grey;
                      if (child == _currentChild) {
                        _color = selectedColor ?? Colors.white;
                      }
                      return Card(
                        shape: const CircleBorder(),
                        elevation: 7,
                        child: SizedBox(
                          height: height * 0.05,
                          child: CircleAvatar(
                            backgroundColor: _color,
                            child: InkWell(
                              customBorder: const CircleBorder(),
                              onTap: () {
                                justChanged = true;
                                currentChild.value = child;
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It's good dear, can you help me to implement asset or network image... Please dear

Comment: The children of this are simply widgets, you can just use the [Image widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image-class.html)

Comment: Brother, How can I use here ListView.Builder. When I trying to use ListViewBuilder image show only first one -- https://ibb.co/TWp8j27 and this is 2nd image https://ibb.co/GnmqyN7  . How can I slider both image bro.

Comment: The `ListView.builder` is probably not what you are looking for. Try [`PageView.builder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageView/PageView.builder.html) with a `PageController`

Comment: Brother, my carosol slider data come from Api as a List. How can I show this data in PageView bro

Comment: The `itemBuilder` parameter gives you an index for you to use. [Here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageView-class.html) is all the explanations about `PageView`